# Inconsistent behaviour for jq in/1

Tags: arrays, jq

The following example from the [jq docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#in) worked as expected --

```sh
$ echo '[1,2]' | jq 'map(in([0,1]))'
[
  true,
  false
]
```

but making the values into strings failed -

```sh
$ echo '["1", "2"]' | jq 'map(in(["0","1"]))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot check whether array has a string key
```

To make sure that this wasn't a shell-quoting issue, I also tried --

```sh
$ echo "[\"1\", \"2\"]" | jq 'map(in(["0","1"]))'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot check whether array has a string key
```

To add to this, the following snippet also fails, which is probably due to a casting of 0 into the boolean false -

```sh
$ echo '[0,1]' | jq 'map(in([1,2]))'       
[
  true,
  true
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually [inside](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#inside) does seem to do the trick (apparently added in v1.5)

```
jq -n '[123,444,565,344,"333",111,1111,87] | map([.]|inside([111,333,344]))'
```

produces

```
[
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false
]
```

Answer (score 6):

You're misunderstanding what `in/1` is doing. It's not testing whether a value is a member of the array, but rather if the value is a member of the object's keys. So for arrays, numbers are expected (the indices) or for objects, strings (the keys). It's exactly the same as `has/1` but the inputs are swapped.

```
$ jq -n '[0,-1,20,9,16,10] | map(in([range(20;30)]))' # 10 item array
[
  true,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  false
]
```

```
$ jq -n '["foo","bar"] | map(in({foo:1,boo:2,bat:3}))'
[
  true,
  false
]
```

If you wanted to test membership in the array, there isn't a builtin but you could craft it yourself. Though `contains/1` is close but not quite since it tests if strings are substrings and not equal. `any/2` could be used to do this.

```
def has_value($value):
    any(.[]; . == $value);

def in_array($arr): # swapped input version
    . as $value | any($arr[]; . == $value);
```

Comment: I understand now. However, I don't feel so comfortable with the way `in` applies to arrays.

Comment: I agree, I would have preferred it behave like the `in` operator as other languages typically define it (such as python or SQL) but it more closely matches javascript's behavior.

Comment: I would also recommend to anyone else who needs to use jeff's recipe, that `is_in` is a good name to use instead of `in_array`.

Answer (score 2):

`index/1` is the builtin that can most conveniently be used for checking array membership.  Although it is not strictly boolean, the semantics of `if` and `//` make it convenient to use as though it were.  If you want a strictly boolean test, then simply use the idiom `index(_) != null`.

`index/1` is worth understanding in detail, so consider reviewing the jq manual and FAQ accordingly. Note also that `INDEX/1` is no relation.